# Discrete version of Bihari-Lasalle inequality

Tags: inequality

I want to know whether any discrete version of the famous Bihari-Lasalle inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihari%E2%80%93LaSalle_inequality) is available in the literature.

Answer (score 0):

I know a rather old result of Agarwal and Thandapani. Please, have a look at Section 3 of this paper:

http://web.math.sinica.edu.tw/bulletin/bulletin_old/d92/9207.pdf

I am sure that much more articles were published on this topic.

Best regards,
Wlodzimierz Fechner